# mail: failed to open stream: Permission denied?

Tags: php, email, sendmail, ssmtp

I get this warning sending mails with php
Warning: mail(1) [function.mail]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/...

- using ssmtp and gmail as smtp
- PHP 5.3.1
- nothing in the logs (no errors)
- the mail gets to destination
- the permissions of the files are rwxrxrx

Permission denied to what?

Even calling something as simple as

mail("mail@domain.com", "subject", "body");

I still getting this warning

Comment: Could you post a code snippet, please? At least the call to `send_mail()`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to paste the function

Comment: I ran into the same issue, and after some discussion on php-general mailing list, a definitive answer was found: http://news.php.net/php.general/309710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be a file permissions problems after all. But not in the scripts, but in the directory.
I ran a `chmod -R 777 *` and the warning went of. upon further examination I found a file called `1`, and this file contained a log of the sent mails.
The warning was php telling me that he was unable to open this file

Solution:

```
 sudo chmod -R 755 *
 sudo chmod  777 1
```

F#$%^% cryptic php error messages

Comment: This is a bad solution, the proper solution would be something along the lines of Packet Tracer's answer. Changing the file ownership so that the user which apache runs as, is able to write to the file. 777 allows any user to write to the file.

Comment: If I had root access or I could modify the server's configuration Packet Tracer would be a solution. But that's not the case.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that the webserver user is not able to write and/or read the mail log file. For a propper configuration:

1) create the folder and the file for the email logging. For example:

```
touch /var/log/php5/mail.log
```

2) set the logging file in php.ini:

```
mail.log = /var/log/php5/mail.log
```

3) set the owner and the group for that folder/file in case needed:

check the owner and the group with

```
ls -la /var/log/php5
```

in case needed, change the group (change www-data for whatever your web server's group is)

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/log/php5
```

in case needed, change the owner (change www-data for whatever your web server's user is)

```
sudo chown -R www-data /var/log/php5
```

Comment: doing this kind of thing is not the best solution:  sudo chmod  777 1

Comment: Totally agree with Packet's Tracer's comment here. The OP solution is a bad approach.

Comment: @Meogi +1 both this and accepted answer have bad decision with 777 permission

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you simplify it?

```
 $mail_sent = mail('address@domain.com', 'subject', 'message');
```

If it does, then you know that mail works.

After that, I would remove the $eol stuff and see if that fixes it. If not, then I would remove the header block and keep removing stuff until it starts working.

Comment: well, actually, i get the warning by calling mail alone. That's why i haven't put any source code.
I DO get the warning by putting mail('address@domain.com', 'subject', 'message');
The mail works, it gets to destination without problems, but the warning stills there...

Comment: What are the permissions on /home/.....?  You need at least read. I would try chmod 777, test mail('address@domain.com', 'subject', 'message'); and see if it works. After that work backwards locking it down.  Also you may need to grant execute on the parent directory.

Comment: In that case I would just suppress it: `@mail('address...`.

Comment: The warning is there for some reason. I'm not going to simply ignore it.
If this serves for something. The mail() call takes up to 2 seconds