# PHP mail: how to override or bypass mail.log setting

Tags: php, email

phpinfo() returns this particular setting which is problematic:

```
mail.log    /var/log/phpmail.log
```

The problem is I can't access the phpmail.log file to set the right CHMOD permissions on it, so my error_log is filling up with the following error each time a mail() fires off:

```
PHP Warning:  mail(/var/log/phpmail.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

If it's at all possible I'd like to skip logging altogether. Otherwise, define a different log file that I can, you know, actually manipulate.

ps - this is not a duplicate of some other thread. I can't go changing the CHMOD values of above mentioned files, my question is about overriding a setting to skip email logging altogether.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mail: failed to open stream: Permission denied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906403/mail-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied)

Answer (score 3):

I would first try to contact whoever is managing your server, he or she should fix this problem.

If that doesn't work, the `mail.log` setting is a [PHP_INI_PERDIR](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php) setting, meaning that:

> Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3)

Obviously, you can't access the system's `php.ini` & `httpd.conf`, but if a `.user.ini` is provided to you, or you're allowed to change settings in `.htaccess`, then that would be a way to solve this.

See:
[.user.ini files](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php)
[Set php.ini Values Using .htaccess](http://davidwalsh.name/php-values-htaccess)

Alternatively, you could consider using Swift Mailer or PHPMailer, which don't need the `mail()` function. In general, using `mail()` is discouraged, it's very basic and fairly difficult to use correctly & securely.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `mail.log` file path in `php.ini` setting to a writable location for Apache or any server you are using.

Comment: If I can't access phpmail.log I sure as heck won't have access to php.ini.

Comment: Dont you have access for php.ini file then use ini_set (http://in2.php.net/ini_set) php

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary `ini_set` doesn't work for this setting, since it's `PHP_INI_PERDIR`.

Answer (score -2):

I'm a newbie in PHP so I don't know if my solution is really a way to solve this issue or if it works due to a coincidence!

I have the same problem presented here: a call to the PHP function *mail()* produces a PHP warning. It's all explained in the first message. I also don't possess the permission to edit the *mail.log* or the directory in which to save it.

Googling, I found a code that call the *mail()* preceded with a *@*. I tried to use the code *@mail()* and it worked!

So this is the working code that I use:

```
$mail_to = "MyAddress@email.com";
$mail_from = $email; // This e-mail address is taken by an HTML form
$mail_subject = "Test PHP function";
$mail_body = "<p>This is the body message for the test of a PHP function!</p>";

// HTML headers
$mail_in_html = "MIME-Version: 1.0
";
$mail_in_html .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
";
$mail_in_html .= "From: <$mail_from>";

// Submission process
if(@mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_body, $mail_in_html))
{
    print "E-mail sent!";
}
else
{
    print "Error: e-mail not sent.";
}
```

Comment: No, don't use @, it's a bad practice - using of Exceptions is better, @ can cause "hidden" errors. You will find it finally find @ before some function after X hours of debugging

Answer (score -3):

I ended up finding this code and it's good enough:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Inserted right before calling the mail() function. Error_log no longer filling up.

Comment: The problem with this is that you won't get *any* errors any more. such as: *mail() failed to send message*, *you forgot argument 2 for mail()*, *mail() is out of stamps*, etc. I would use this only as a last resort.