# Changing PHP mail.log path on a shared server

Tags: php, email

I am trying to change the location of the php_mail.log file which is automatically placed in the root directory when sending email using the PHP mail() function.  My website is hosted on a shared server at Siteground.  phpinfo() shows a local value of "php_mail.log" (no path) for the mail.log directive.

I tried changing the location (to a folder named "mail-log" outside the root directory) by adding the following to the php.ini file ("usr" was replaced by the proper username):

```
mail.log = /home/usr/mail-log/php_mail.log
```

However, this seemed to be ignored as the php_mail.log file was still placed in the root directory.

A similar post (here: [PHP mail: how to override or bypass mail.log setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871254/php-mail-how-to-override-or-bypass-mail-log-setting)) indicates that the location can be changed using the php.ini file.  However, as I noted, it seems to have no effect.

Is it possible that a server setting is overriding the change in the php.ini file?  I contacted Siteground, but they were not helpful.  Any insight or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to have apache restarted to apply the settings..

Comment: According to Siteground support, it doesn't sound like it is possible for me to restart Apache.  Is there another way?