# How to connect dropdown menu to email - php

Tags: php, html, email, drop-down-menu

I can't seem to find my error when trying to connect a dropdown menu to my contact page. I've followed my error log, but my configurations are messed up somewhere as I'm not too familiar with email, thank you in advance for any advice.

```
<?php

/***************** Configuration *****************/

// Enter your email, where you want to receive the messages.
$contact_email_to = "EMAIL NAME";

// Subject prefix
$contact_subject_prefix = " ";

// Name too short error text
$contact_error_name = "Name is too short or empty!";

// Email invalid error text
$contact_error_email = "Please enter a valid email!";

// Subject too short error text
$contact_error_subject = "Subject is too short or empty!";

// Message too short error text
$contact_error_message = "Too short message! Please enter something.";


if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    // The Request must be Ajax POST, enter a message for direct access requests.
    die('Invalid Request!'); 
}

if( isset($_POST) ) {

    $name = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $email = filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $company = filter_var($_POST["company"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message = filter_var($_POST["message"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $subject = ($_GET["subject"]);

    if(strlen($name)<4){ 
        die($contact_error_name);
    }

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){  
        die($contact_error_email);
    }

    if(strlen($company)<3){ 
        die($contact_error_subject);
    }

    if(strlen($message)<3){ 
        die($contact_error_message);
    }

    $sendemail = mail($contact_email_to, $company, $subject, $message,
         "From: ".$name." <".$email.">" . PHP_EOL
        ."Reply-To: ".$email . PHP_EOL
        ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion()
    );

    if( $sendemail ) {
        echo 'OK';
    } else {
        echo 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.';
    }
}
?>
```

```html
<div class="row contact-wrap">
<div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
<div class="col-md-8">
   <div id="sendmessage">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
   <div id="errormessage"></div>
   <form action="" method="post" role="form" class="contactForm">
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
     <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" data-rule="email" data-msg="Please enter a valid email" />
     <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Your Company" data-rule="minlen:4" data-msg="Please enter at least 4 chars" />
     <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <select name="subject" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
        <option value="">---</option>
        <option value="sales">Sales</option>
        <option value="safety">Safety</option>
        <option value="accountsP">Accounts Payable</option>
        <option value="accountsR">Accounts Receivable</option>
        <option value="accountsR">Human Resources</option>
        <option value="accountsR">Operations</option>
        <option value="accountsR">Equipment</option>
        <option value="accountsR">Management</option>
     </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" data-rule="required" data-msg="Please write something for us" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
     <div class="validation"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" required="required">Submit Message</button></div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand from your explanation, you are unable to get `subject` value. Problem is `method`. You are using `POST` method to submit form and using `GET` to retrieve value.

```
$subject = ($_GET["subject"]);
```

should be

```
$subject = ($_POST["subject"]);
```

If you are unable to send email yet, you need to debug. There are tons of reasons. I am listing few based upon your use-case and my understanding.

1. Enable error reporting - this will allow you to see all errors, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php#answer-6575502)
2. Activate PHP's custom log for emails - check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871254/php-mail-how-to-override-or-bypass-mail-log-setting#answer-21871292)
3. If step#1 and step#2 doesn't help, try different mailer - PHPMailer or SwiftMailer

Comment: It's my predefined error message 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'

Comment: Is this on localhost or live server?

Comment: This is on live server

Comment: Updated the answer based upon our conversation. Let me know whether it helps or not.