# Opencart get error when send email

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

Recently i moved my opencart shop to a new host but i found new issue in sending email by system, after user submit an order, system send a confirmation email for him and also for me (admin) successfully but user see an error:

> Warning: mail(/var/log/php_mail.log): faild to open stream: Permission
>   denied in /**/**/system/library/mail.php on line 164

and also when i want to add a history to his order, when i check `Notify Customer` i see an error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 OK Warning:
>   mail(/var/log/php_mail.log): faild to open stream: Permission denied
>   in /**/**/system/library/mail.php on line 164

What this mean? and what's the problem?

*I googled but none of results related to sending email case.*

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems that there is some issue related to permissions. Check [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906403/mail-failed-to-open-stream-permission-denied) and [Link2](https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=112620). Or simply givewrite permissions to your whole opencart files folder.

Comment: @Nimish Thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue. for future, if anyone face with this problem:

*in e-mail setting should add e-mail with a `-f` at the beginning:*

```
-fyou@youremail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If the error message continues with **"MAIL FROM not accepted from server"** you should change **system/library/mail/smtp.php**

Look for these 2 lines (mine was at line 156):

```
fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->smtp_username . '>XVERP' . "\r\n");
fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->smtp_username . '>' . "\r\n");
```

and change it to:

```
fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>XVERP' . "\r\n");
fputs($handle, 'MAIL FROM: <' . $this->from . '>' . "\r\n");
```